# Android 4.0 ImageView setImageBitmap does not work

Tags: android, imageview

I develop a App with ffmpeg to decode a media frame. I filled a Bitmap object with the decode result and use ImageView.setImageBitmap to display the bitmap. 
In Android 2.3 it works well, but in Android 4.0 or up it doesn't work.
The code is simply :

```
imgVedio.setImageBitmap(bitmapCache);//FIXME:in 4.0 it displays nothing
```

Then I tried write the Bitmap to a file and reload the file to display.

```
String fileName = "/mnt/sdcard/myImage/video.jpg";
FileOutputStream b = null;
try 
{
    b = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
    bitmapCache.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, b);// write data to file
} 
catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally 
{
    try 
    {
        if(b != null)
        {
            b.flush();
            b.close();
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileName);
imgVedio.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

It works, but the performance is too poor.
So can someone help me resolve the problem?

Answer (score 14):

I think it's an out of memory problem, you can fix it using this method :

```
private Bitmap loadImage(String imgPath) {
    BitmapFactory.Options options;
    try {
        options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = 2;
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgPath, options);
        return bitmap;
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

The "inSampleSize" option will return a smaller image and save memory. You can just call this in the ImageView.setImageBitmap :

```
imgVedio.setImageBitmap(loadImage(IMAGE_PATH));
```

Comment: This was the only answer I could find that addressed the issue of a out of memory problem. Thank you

Comment: Is there any way to detect if loading the Bitmap failed so we can increase the inSampleSize value only if needed?